# Heroku rake db:schema:load table does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rake

In my heroku staging envinronment, I ran

```
heroku pg:reset
```

followed by

```
heroku rake db:schema:load
```

and I get this error

```
-- create_table("cash_drawer_open", {:force=>true})
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  table "cash_drawer_open" does not exist
```

Of course the table doesn't exist!! I am trying to CREATE it...  what have I done wrong?

This all works just fine on my local postgre development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is working fine locally, you could just do a `heroku db:push`. Just make sure you have the `taps` gem installed and that should do the job.

Answer (score 4):

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to recreate database:

```
heroku rake db:create
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the migrations again

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```